# Change array key back in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Basically, let's say I got this array :

```
array[0] = "zero",

array[1] = "one",

array[2] = "two",

array[3] = "three"
```

I unset `array[2]`, so the output becomes :

```
array[0] = "zero",

array[1] = "one",

array[3] = "three"
```

I want the output becomes :

```
array[0] = "zero",

array[1] = "one",

array[2] = "three"
```

Is there a way for array key to adjust like that? Sorry in advance for the messy writing.

Comment: array_values will solve it.

Comment: @wendy: please leave meta discussion out of the question section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `array_values()` after the `unset()`.

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: fair enough. reading

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what you're looking for:

```
<?php

// Original array
$array = array();
$array[0] = "zero";
$array[1] = "one";
$array[2] = "two";
$array[3] = "three";

// Values with keys
var_dump( $array );

// Unset the item
unset( $array[2] );

// Set the array values
$array = array_values( $array );

// Output the re-keyed array
var_dump( $array );  

?>
```

Comment: @r3wt the question is not marked as duplicate yet, you may just have flagged it as duplicate. Did you down vote for that ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: `$array = array_values($array);`

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php